# What kind of OCR Java library should I use in Android?

Tags: java, android, ocr

I would like to build an Android application that, via an OCR library, should scan a picture extracting text from it .

What Java library should I use?

Comment: Google recently released an API to achieve this: https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't know how good it is (it definitely needs to be trained first), but there is [Ron Cemer's Java OCR library](http://www.roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr).

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a very extensible option or have a specific problem domain you could consider rolling your own using the [Java Object Oriented Neural Engine](http://www.jooneworld.com/).

I used it successfully in a personal project to identify the letter from an image such as [this](http://www.gamerbytes.com/xnawordsoup.jpg), you can find all the source for the OCR component of my application on github, [here](http://github.com/dukedave/wordsolver/tree/2e03f0dcf7c9fcfef60d6df0dfd1036c3660a30d/src/ocr).

Answer (score 6):

try tesseract,
checkout this article
[http://www.itwizard.ro/interfacing-cc-libraries-via-jni-example-tesseract-163.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20121028185436/http://www.itwizard.ro/interfacing-cc-libraries-via-jni-example-tesseract-163.html)
and this example
http://code.google.com/p/mezzofanti/

Edit:
some more facts
- tesseract is one of the best open source OCR used by google
- there is training data available for many languages
- mezzofanti is an android app that uses tesseract
- beware: OCR does use a lot of CPU power. trying to OCR a A4 page with your T-Mob G1 will take a lot of time and the result may not impress you ;-)

Comment: tesseract does work but its reading ability is quite poor for even the simplest text.

Comment: thats why you have to train it @mP. - I was able to get good results with the default training while implementing ISBN reader. Try this link, I didn't use their experiences yet but I have it in my bookmarks for a long time And I think it is good source od info http://vbridge.co.uk/2012/11/05/how-we-tuned-tesseract-to-perform-as-well-as-a-commercial-ocr-package/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OCR feature from Google Docs. 
Check the **Documents List Data  API** http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#OCR