# Translate a picture to text on Android?

Tags: android, ocr

I know that google goggles will translate a picture to text. What I want to do is allow the user to take a picture (no problem), translate that picture to text(?) and then do some processing on the text (no problem).

Is there any API on android that allows this? or is there any way to programtically communicate with google goggles? I would hate to have the user use goggles then select the saved file with my app.....

Comment: Tesseract seems to be the best option, This article http://www.itwizard.ro/interfacing-cc-libraries-via-jni-example-tesseract-163.html details what needs to be done and this example http://code.google.com/p/mezzofanti/ is money.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at [Is there any free OCR library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr) and [What kind of OCR Java library should I use in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062578/what-kind-of-ocr-java-library-should-i-use-in-android) if you want libraries that do the translation on the phone itself.

However, Google also provides a WebAPI that does this. http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-docs-ocr.html

Just remember that OCR (optical character recognition) is, as of now, an inexact science and you won't get flawless transcription in all cases...

Comment: awesome dude, thanx. I guess I should have been doing my searches on OCR instead of "image to text" :)

I think that the tesjeract and its JNI wrapper will do just fine.
http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/
http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/

Answer (score 1):

check this example it's used in google translate to get text from image it's use google services

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/ocr-codelab