# extract text from image

Tags: java, android, image

i have an image i am using aspire and Aspose api for image extraction but output getting blank 
nothing is getting from image .after that i can use test4j but output is not getting any thing 
how can i extract text from image in my image is shown bellow.that image is hand drawn from the android mobile phone!

my image:

[image: http://puu.sh/9ndSR/9ef7a0cb07.png]

please suggest me how can i extract text or which OCR properties i can use thanks in advance

Comment: Implement your own AI techniques.

Comment: I think you are joking. I do not believe that there is OCR implementation that can recognize such hand written characters.

Comment: i am text extracting in java i hope not concern with android  @Der Golem

Comment: you can use **tesseract library** see -  https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

Comment: i tried that but that library does not work such type of images .they do not recognize the text.they given wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

I am Social Media Developer at Aspose. I have reported your issue to Aspose.OCR developers through Aspose Support forums on your behalf. You can track the progress of the issue on below thread:

http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/552365/getting-blank-output-for-hand-writing-recognition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is some kind of text recognition.

Coding this by yourself will need much time and most likely more experience than you have.

This leaves us with getting some library for the job.

A quick Google search for `java text recognition` turned up some paid-for libs and also `ocr4j`([Link](http://ocr4j.sourceforge.net/)).

You might want to search further.

**edit**

There are also [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904507/translate-a-picture-to-text-on-android) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533273/best-ocr-optical-character-recognition-example-in-android) SO questions that handle android ocr.