# on-board ocr library for android app

Tags: android, ocr

I am trying to create an OCR app for android. I want to be able to do it on the device itself rather than sending it to a server and then see the results. Is there a library available for it? I can consider buying as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062578/what-kind-of-ocr-java-library-should-i-use-in-android

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While I know zilch about Android development, what I could offer you is to explore the option of porting 'tesseract'. Have used it a little, and few other FOSS OCR tools (some actually based on tesseract), and have found it to be best of the FOSS lot. AFAIR, it does only basic recognition, and you need to massage the document prior to feeding it to tesseract. Where commercial s/w surpasses FOSS tools, is the parapharnalia of preprocessing/massaging they are able to do, and even some postprocessing -- guessing tables and fitting text/unrecognized graphics back into positionally accurate locations on page, and converting into other document formats.

Tesseract can be tried on a regular Linux desktop on your favourite distro. IIRC, there is even a MS-Windows version as well, i.e. if you care.