# Is there a free OCR Engine for Android?

Tags: android, ocr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of OCR Java library should I use in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062578/what-kind-of-ocr-java-library-should-i-use-in-android)

I am looking for a Free Ocr Library to use in my application but I didn't find one. So If you can say me one and maybe also an Example application or something like this I'm gonna be happy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OCR feature from Google Docs. 
Check the **Documents List Data  API** http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#OCR