# scanning a document using camera in Android and get numbers

Tags: android, numbers, android-camera

scanning a document using camera in Android and get numbers..
can i use the android camera to scan any document for numbers and return them to textview
?
for example focusing the camera to an credit card numbers and the camera print the numbers to a text filed .
i'm new to android so please be easy on me :p .

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786367/android-capture-a-document-scan-it-using-camera I hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

The comment by ilay zeidman is enough. But would like to give you steps to get it done.

1. Integrate the OCR library [from here](http://javaocr.sourceforge.net/).
2. Capture the image. And pass the image to OCR library.
3. OCR library will give you the content in some format which you can use it further.