# Image recognition convert an image to text in android

Tags: android, image-processing, text

I am now currently doing a project on image to text convertion, i have go through various process like canny algorithm and so many, but did not get a solution.Finally i got a video in the following link [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Mds_NDQotc&feature=plcp&context=C428f513VDvjVQa1PpcFNa26jZifCC1B9NUmb71uufeBy1RolOQLg=)

i need exactly the same application now how can i  implement this please find me a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to recognize the characters from a picture, here are some related posts

[Is there any free OCR library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr)

[What kind of OCR Java library should I use in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062578/what-kind-of-ocr-java-library-should-i-use-in-android)

Proof-of-concept word input from camera for Android
http://code.google.com/p/wordsnap-ocr/

Comment: its a ndk project right i dont know how t o handle ndk? use full answer thank you

Comment: Ten year later Google has native solution for this task https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2/android