# Java OCR algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm, ocr

I am looking to make an android app which allows a user to take a photo of a number plate of a car and then based the image, extract the letters in to a string.

I have really struggled to find a single open source app library for android thats simply lets you pass an image and it returns the text.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a library for doing just this, or if not if anyone knew of a particular algorithm that i could implement?

Kind regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062578/what-kind-of-ocr-java-library-should-i-use-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Ron Cemer has a really nice one.
http://www.roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr

But the most popular is Tesseract(http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/), but you'd have to use a JNI wrapper, like Tesjeract(http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/).

Here's Mezzofanti (http://code.google.com/p/mezzofanti/) an open source app that uses Tesjeract with Tesseract.

There's also Abbyy's paid one:
http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/android/

Comment: i had already tried with the first link you provided but i could find no api - and it states that it requires linux?

Comment: Linux isn't necessary. He just uses it to show you how to compile and test the library. The library is on the SourceForge project he links to at the bottom http://javaocr.sourceforge.net/