# OCR (Image to text) in Android

Tags: android, image-processing, ocr

How can I implement an OCR function in my android app? I want to make an app that takes a picture and translates a text from it. Any APIS or tutorials for that?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of OCR Java library should I use in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062578/what-kind-of-ocr-java-library-should-i-use-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Here some additional links I found that may assist you on configuring tesseract. I personally have not use this, as I personally opted for 2D code approach.

- http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/using-tesseract-tools-for-android-to-create-a-basic-ocr-app/
- http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

### Original answer

Well without knowing anything about your app, I would like to note that you probably could not beat [Google Googles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.unveil&hl=en)  when it comes to OCR features.  Maybe you can add additional detail what kind of text do you want to be able to translate? So we know your not reinventing the wheel :)

I found a few links
https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/
http://ocrsdk.com/producttour/many-more/

But if I may suggest, if you it specific message that can you want to parse, I would recommend actually using QR barcode. You can convert a CSV file into 2D code and then have your app scan it then parse it to do some custom feature.

Here library I used for 2D code and found it quite useful in the past. [Zxing which is open source and free to use](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I just want my android app to convert an image to text and return(display)it, including all kinds of character(numbers, letters...)I've seen this tesseract, but i dont know how to use it.Could you help me?
Ps: it would only parse characters, not barcodes
thanks

Comment: It would just 'extract' the text(characters) from th image and return(display it).

Comment: It's just like what google goggles does with texts, but i want to make an app that does the same thing :)

Comment: I updated my Answer to include some additional resource how to configure tesseract to work on Android. Try the links out and see if you can get it setup. It it works then accept the answer or come back with updated question.