# How to extract the text from a jpeg image in android

Tags: android, image, camera

I am developing an application in which I have to scan a hard copy of a form through the application and the form contains an integer number at the right hand corner. Now I want to extract that number and show it an edit text. How can I do it? For example:-

In the attached image I have to extract the text "If" and put it in an edit text.[image]

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: It's called OCR, search for library that will do work for you, because it's too complicated to do it by yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062578/what-kind-of-ocr-java-library-should-i-use-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually You need to use third party library for this. You can use Tess4j library for this. The process of extracting text from image is called "Optical Character Recognition (OCR)".

You can go for "Tess4j". Using this lib, you can achieve your results.Don't go for "Asprise OCR". Because in android you can't use buffered reader image related class, it is for cre java only. The result quality of "Tess4j" is really good.